# Owl slider on dynamically created scope array in angular js

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, owl-carousel

I have an array which will be filled with values dynamically. I want to apply owls slider on each items in array.
If the array is already filled with item my code works fine, but array with dynamically filled values not working. Please suggest , any help will really appreciate. Thanks in advance.

Here is my code on [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/ev95KJ6hBtKViK15x1V0?p=preview)

***My html:***

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="plunker">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <title>AngularJS Plunker</title>
  <script>
  document.write('<base href="' + document.location + '" />');
  </script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/owl-carousel/1.3.3/owl.carousel.min.css" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/owl-carousel/1.3.3/owl.theme.min.css" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/owl-carousel/1.3.3/owl.transitions.min.css" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/owl-carousel/1.3.3/owl.carousel.min.js" />
  <script data-require="angular.js@1.3.x" src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.3.15/angular.js" data-semver="1.3.15"></script>
  <script data-require="jquery@2.1.3" data-semver="2.1.3" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.3.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/owl-carousel/1.3.3/owl.carousel.min.js"></script>
  <script src="app.js"></script>
</head>

<body ng-controller="MainCtrl">
  <data-owl-carousel class="owl-carousel" data-options="{navigation: true, pagination: false, rewindNav : false}">
    <div owl-carousel-item="" ng-repeat="item in ::items1" class="item">
      <p>{{::item}}</p>
    </div>
  </data-owl-carousel>
  <data-owl-carousel class="owl-carousel" data-options="{navigation: false, pagination: true, rewindNav : false}">
    <div owl-carousel-item="" ng-repeat="item in ::items2" class="item">
      <p>{{::item}}</p>
    </div>
  </data-owl-carousel>
  <button id="add" add-data>Add</button>
</body>

</html>
```

***App.js***

```
    var app = angular.module('plunker', []);

app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.items1 = [];
  $scope.items2 = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10];
}).directive("owlCarousel", function() {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        transclude: false,
        link: function (scope) {
            scope.initCarousel = function(element) {
              // provide any default options you want
                var defaultOptions = {
                };
                var customOptions = scope.$eval($(element).attr('data-options'));
                // combine the two options objects
                for(var key in customOptions) {
                    defaultOptions[key] = customOptions[key];
                }
                // init carousel
                $(element).owlCarousel(defaultOptions);
            };
        }
    };
})
.directive('owlCarouselItem', [function() {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        transclude: false,
        link: function(scope, element) {
          // wait for the last item in the ng-repeat then call init
            if(scope.$last) {
                scope.initCarousel(element.parent());
            }
        }
    };
}])
.directive('addData', [function() {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        transclude: false,
        link: function(scope, element) {
          // wait for the last item in the ng-repeat then call init
            element.on('click', function() {
              scope.items1.push(5); 
              console.log(scope.items1);
            });

        }
    };
}]);
```